# Can a <default-action-ref> in a package in struts.xml refer to another namespace or package?

Tags: struts2, namespaces

I have a default package in my `struts.xml` file with namespace "/". This package is extended by another package called global which has namespace "/global".

I would like it so that users who make a request to:

```
http://someserver:port/webAppRoot/
```

Are redirected to the default-action-ref in the **global** package (instead of the default package). I understand the default-action-ref must be declared in the default package, because it has namespace "/" which is exactly the namespace of the incoming request.

Is my only option to put the default action in the default package?

Answer (score 0):

You can put `default-action-ref` to any package, but only one per package

> The default action features should be set up so that there is only one default action per namespace. If you have multiple packages declaring a default action with the same namespace, there is no guarantee which action will be the default.

In the `name` attribute you specify the action name in this package that will be called if the real name of the action is not found.

The default action is inherited if your package extends a package that has already defined `default-action-ref`.